# setup project created in VS2017 15.3 no longer supported in VS2017 15.5?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

Discovered to my horror, that after updating all my Visual Studio 2017 instances to version 15.5 (from version 15.3), none of the setup projects will load and I get a message saying they are not supported.  I've tried several Desktop applications, all developed in VS2017 and these setup projects won't load.
Is there any workaround to this (without creating all new Setup projects - some are quite complex)?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the issue turned out to be that the Installer Projects extension was corrupted, so I renamed my setup project, then re-downloaded/re-installed the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects" extension, closed Visual Studio, renamed my Setup project to what it was, opened the solution again & added the Setup project back to the solution.

*NOTE - the other PC running VS2017 never had the Installer Projects integrated w/VS in the first place (it was more for web development), the reason why they wouldn't open.*

Worked like a charm!